# Can I access the local filesystem from a Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I am trying to write a simple media player as a chrome packaged app, and to do that I need to access any folder from the filesystem directly from whithin the app.

**Pseudocode**

```
chrome.runtime.getFolderContents(
     'c:/my_music',
     function(contents){ 
          // Do something 
     });
```

Is that possible? And if so, how? Searching didn't give me a clear "can not do" so... Can I?

Comment: A new API is being developed (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/apps-dev/fu1TyjdYLEc). For now, chrome.mediaGalleries API (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries.html) can be used since you're writing a media player.

Comment: This is pretty cool and answers my question perfectly. If you want to add this comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Just to add to the previous comment, for this use case you should definitely use the media galleries API unless it has features missing. If it does lack in features and you find yourself wishing you had that directory access proposal, make sure you file a bug at crbug.com and feel free to cc me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Media Galleries API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries.html) offers "access media files (images, video, audio) from the user's local disks (with the user's consent)."

It is best suited for your application, as it asks the user for just enough permission to do what you want, and not more.